# Attempted import error: 'addLocaleData' is not exported from 'react-intl'

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

It's return error when i try this code

react-intl version 3.1.6 &&
react version 16.9

```
import { IntlProvider, FormattedMessage , addLocaleData} from 'react-intl';
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm still investigating but it looks like addLocaleData was removed as a breaking change for v3.

https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x

This was a bit confusing for me too because a lot of the tutorials and guides out there still use addLocaleData.

Comment: Hi Brian,
any luck finding out any more info on addLocaleData being removed?

Comment: Hey, the reasons for why addLocaleData are written in the upgrade-guide linked in my original post.

Comment: the link is broken now. New link (2020-09-17): https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x/

Answer (score 2):

The historical context is that `react-intl` was written back when `Intl.PluralRules` & `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat` did not exist. Fast forward to now, `Intl.PluralRules` is officially in the Intl JS spec, and `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat` is stage 3 so we've changed the strategy for locale-data to polyfills instead on browsers that don't have those APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the ideal solution but downgrading react-intl to `^2.8.0` is a quick and easy option.